# Do I need to std::move an std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, stdinitializerlist

I want to pass a list-initialized vector to a worker function through a wrapper. I don't need the values in the original function (main), so should I move it?

The doc states that:

> copying a std::initializer_list does not copy the underlying objects.

So costs are probably minimal, but is there still an advantage to moving it or is the list copy-elided and the vector directly list-initialized?

**(Compiling) Code**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


void worker(std::vector<int>&& some_ints)
{
    std::cout << "I hope my ints arrive here without further overhead :)" << std::endl;
}

void wrapper(std::vector<int>&& some_ints)
{
    worker(std::move(some_ints));
}

int main()
{
    wrapper( { 1, 5 } ); // <-- std::move here?
}
```

Comment: @bolov: so my example is correct here? Do I need take std::vector in as refref even in the wrapper func?

Comment: 1. See @dfrib's answer. 2. Even if you'd be calling let's say `wrapper(std::vector<int>{1, 5})`, the argument is already a prvalue, so no need to move.

Answer (score 1):

A braced-init-list is not a `std:initializer_list`.

Here:

```
wrapper( { 1, 5 } );
```

overload resolution finds the `void wrapper(std::vector<int>&&)` overload which is a viable overload for the call: creating a temporary `std::vector<int>` object (by list-initialization via the `std::initializer_list<T>` constructor of `std::vector<T>`) which binds to the rvalue reference parameter of the `wrapper` function.

Trying to move a braced-init-list

```
wrapper(std::move({ 1, 5 }));  // error
```

is illegal (`T` in the `std::move<T>(T&&)` function template cannot be deduced).

Comment: Thanks. So basically the brace initializer list converts to an std::initializer_list to match up with vector's constructor?
One question still: Do I need to take std::vector in as an rvalue reference in wrapper() or is it optional?